# Upgraded to dojo 1.10 cannot use dojo.require

Tags: dojo

I am upgrading from dojo 1.3 to dojo 1.10 and have found that dojo.require does not work. This is a VERY legacy application running on a network NOT connected to the Internet.

I read that I need to put dojo into "legacy loader mode" which I have tried by setting "async" to "falsy or 'sync', but nothing seems to work. I keep getting the following error:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'require'

Am I missing some other piece?

```
<script>
   var dojoConfig = {sync: 'legacyAsync'};
</script>
<script src="{path to dojo v1.10}"></script>
....
<link (dijit them></link>
<script>
    dojo.require('dijit.form.ComboButton');
    .....
    dojo.require('dijit.Menu');
    dojo.require('dijit.MenuItem);
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide a small example of how you are configuring/loading Dojo and using require?

Comment: Also, to make matters worse... my application allows for "exporting a web site" which means all the modules will need to be loaded from a file:/// prefix.

Comment: You may want to upgrade step by step, so you would try moving up to 1.4, then 1.5 etc, and take a look at the release notes as you go.  http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/releasenotes

Answer (score 0):

You should not be setting `async: 'legacyAsync'` (I assume the `sync` in your question is a typo) - you should just set it to `false` (or leave it out entirely, since that's the default, specifically *for* backwards compatibility).

I was only able to reproduce your error with it explicitly set to `legacyAsync`, which is a mode which mimics legacy cross-domain builds of Dojo.